# HTML & CSS: Sorting table buttons not working

Tags: html, css, datatables

I'm using datatable.js and I'm trying to make my table sortable. The sorting works but I can't figure out why my icon doesn't appear.

Results:
[image]

Expected:
[image]

My code:

```css
table.users thead .sorting:before, table.users thead .sorting_asc:before, table.users thead .sorting_asc_disabled:before, table.users thead .sorting_desc:before, table.users thead .sorting_desc_disabled:before {
  top: 2px;
  right: 1em;
  content: "\2191";
}

div.dataTables_wrapper div.dataTables_filter {
  text-align: right;
}

table.users thead .sorting:after, table.users thead .sorting:before, table.users thead .sorting_asc:after, table.users thead .sorting_asc:before, table.users thead .sorting_asc_disabled:after, table.users thead .sorting_asc_disabled:before, table.users thead .sorting_desc:after, table.users thead .sorting_desc:before, table.users thead .sorting_desc_disabled:after, table.users thead .sorting_desc_disabled:before {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: .9em;
  display: block;
  opacity: .3;
}
```

```html
<table id="users" class="table table-hover users" width="100%">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="sorting">Nickname</th>
       <th>Rank</th>
       <th>SteamID</th>
       <th>Date</th>
       <th>Last Access</th>
      <th class="disabled-sorting text-right">Actions</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following is straightforward to implement, but there are a couple of differences from what you requested.

The table:

[image: sort arrows]

The styles:

```
/* hide the default sort order triangles */
table.dataTable thead .sorting,
table.dataTable thead .sorting_asc,
table.dataTable thead .sorting_desc {
  background-image: none;
}

/* not sorted */
table.dataTable thead .sorting:after {
  padding-left: 1em;
  content: "\2191\2193";
  opacity: .3;
}

/* sorted ascending */
table.dataTable thead .sorting_asc:after {
  padding-left: 1em;
  content: "\2191";
}

/* sorted descending */
table.dataTable thead .sorting_desc:after {
  padding-left: 1em;
  content: "\2193";
}
```

Points to note:

1) This uses the class names provided by DataTables - there are no custom classes used.

2) The arrows are not right-adjusted within each heading cell. Instead, they are slightly to the right of the labels. If your column headings do not have clear borders, then this may actually be a good thing.

3) For a sorted column, only one arrow is shown. Your screenshot expects both arrows (one with less opacity).

If this doesn't meet your needs, it may at least point you in the direction you want to go.

Comment: Thank you! It actually was better than what I wanted!