# sorting the icons of datatables

Tags: jquery, datatables

right now, the `datatables` icons are appearing like this on the following `jsbin`

```
http://live.datatables.net/yohewano/1/edit
```

i am trying to modify css to use custom css icon to show the icons like this

```
https://prnt.sc/1q6i2ar
```

i am playing with css but can't seems to figure out what is wrong here

playing with CSS

```
table.dataTable thead .sorting_asc {
  background: url("http://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.0/images/sort_asc.png") no-repeat center left;
}
table.dataTable thead .sorting_desc {
  background: url("http://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.0/images/sort_desc.png") no-repeat center left;
}
table.dataTable thead .sorting {
  background: url("http://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.0/images/sort_both.png") no-repeat center left;
}
```

Comment: I am not sure what the title means - I think it means "how do I change the sort (arrow) icons?". You may also want to try to clarify what you are trying to do - it is not clear to me.

Comment: If you are trying to change the arrow icons, then take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60902123/12567365) for one approach, which you should be able to merge with your attempt.  Use `:before` instead of (or as well as) `:after`, for positioning.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [HTML & CSS: Sorting table buttons not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60894014/html-css-sorting-table-buttons-not-working)

Comment: it does 50%, i want to put one arrow on the left side of the column and another one on the right side of the column